# Rendering average rating on a single product - probably an easy solve, but cannot find the problem

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to show display the average rating for a given single product from every ratings made by users on this single product.

Which I managed to do. However my code seems to render all products and relating reviews and not just the specific product.

Clearly, I am telling the code, somewhere, to render all products instead of one. But I am not too sure where. I think it's coming form the code in my views.py.

Something to specify also, in the same page, I am trying to display:

1. Average review per product (that's what I am working on)
2. All reviews from different user on the specific product (that works)

Is it 2. that creates a problem? Should I also make a reference to the product_id in the second line of the views too? (if so, where?)

**Models**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Product Name', max_length=120, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table='Product'
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class ReviewRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating_1 = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING1,default=0)    
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s - %s'%(self.user, self.product, self.date_added)
```

**Views**

```
from django.db.models import Avg
 
def Notes (request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    data = Product.objects.order_by('name').annotate(
        avg_rating_1 =Avg('comments__rating_1 '),

    return render(request, 'main/notes.html',{'product':product, 'data':data})
```

**Template**

```
{% for ReviewRating in data%}

{{ReviewRating.avg_rating_1 }}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

All I needed to change the views from `order_by` to `filter(pk=product_id)`,  so:

```
from django.db.models import Avg
 
def Notes (request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    data = Product.objects.filter(pk=product_id).annotate(
        avg_rating_1 =Avg('comments__rating_1 '),

    return render(request, 'main/notes.html',{'product':product, 'data':data})
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you should use aggregation and @property decorator to use this method as a field inside you project. Here example to your code.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Product Name', max_length=120, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table='Product'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
    
    @property
    def rating(self):
        rating = self.comments.aggregate(Avg('rating_1'))['rating_1__avg']
```

And inside your template you can use this like this:

```py
{% for ReviewRating in champagnes %}

{{ReviewRating.rating_1 }}

{% endfor %}
```

> Do not forget to import Avg
> `from django.db.models import Avg`

Comment: Hi there. I didnt work, at least in didnt improve the situation. In this case the calculation of the average works. It's only that the template shows the average for all the products, instead of the specific product page. Does that make sense?